# ISEXP : error : -5008: This 32-bit package cannot include 64-bit data

Tags: installshield-le

Recently i upgraded my visual studio 2008 installer project to InstallShield Limited Edition project into Visual Studio 2013. I was able to build the solution from visual studio and from my Nant build script. My solution build platform is x86/Release and my installshield limited edition project build platform is singleimage without specifying any platform. My computer is Win32 and i installed installshield limited edition for 32 bit.

Now i added one merge module in the InstallShield Limited Edition project which can be run in both Win32 and Win64. The signature of the merge module specifies that it can be executed in both Win32 and Win64.

But as long as i added the merge module and built the solution, i got the following error

**ISEXP : error : -5008: This 32-bit package cannot include 64-bit data. The 64-bit data may come from a merge module.**

My merge module is developed by other party and they said it should be worked in both Win32 and Win64.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Windows Installer, you have to [choose between making a 32-bit or a 64-bit package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx). The 32-bit package can install on a 64-bit system but can only access 32-bit locations; the 64-bit package cannot install on a 32-bit system, but can access 64-bit locations on a 64-bit system.

The error you quote is to avoid letting a merge module change your whole package from 32-bit to 64-bit, as that can cause you compatibility problems that are difficult to diagnose. If you want to use that merge module as is, you must do something in your project to indicate you want a 64-bit package, such as adding a file or registry key that installs to a 64-bit location. Alternately, if you need to support 32-bit systems, you should request the other party properly separate their 32-bit and 64-bit merge modules.